# Do sellers need lots of capital to accept purchase orders?

Tags: purchase

I have a product that I could sell to school districts. As I understand, school districts typically use [purchase orders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purchase_order). I have heard of vendors banning school districts because they didn't get paid. This makes me wonder, when someone uses a purchase order, does the seller receive the money first, then send the product, or do they often have to ship the product and then receive it later?

Comment: Purchase Orders are definitely “buy now, pay later”.

Comment: Typically, “net 30” (or 60 or 90), with 1.5% penalty every month after that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking about. You mentioned "school districts", but there are hundreds of thousands of those, if not more, in the world. You mentioned "purchase order", but you're asking about payment terms. It seems like a completely random set of words, frankly. What's your question, and how does it relate to personal finance?

Answer (score 3):

Large companies, and many government agencies use a purchase order to obtain goods and in some cases services.

The nature of the purchase order is that the person that is wanting the goods doesn't have the power to write a company check. The PO process is used to get the proper approval from the organization before the vendor fulfills the order. Once the product has been received the terms of the PO specify that the bill will be paid after the vendor submits it.

There is typically a set number of days between billing and the payment. Thirty to 90 days are typical.

In the case of large orders that can't be delivered at one time, or orders when the recipient wants to spread the deliveries over time there may be several billing and paying cycles.

For the vendor they want to make the payment delay as short as possible. The issue for them is that they have to obtain the goods or raw materials, complete the assembly, ship them, bill the purchasing organization, and then wait. During that time period they have to pay their suppliers, pay their workers, and then wait for the money. The costs are either handled from cash flow from other orders, a loan, or a line of credit.

Another risk with a PO can be the uncertain timeline between expressing interest in the product and being able to officially order the product with the Purchase order. Some organizations can complete the review in a few days, some take months. I am certain that some expected orders never materialize. I am also sure that orders finally become official weeks after they were expected, but still have the same deadline, making them impossible to fulfill without overtime.

Comment: There was a story in the news recently about Tesla sending a PO to a local bakery and then canceling it a few days later. Vendors eventually learn with whom not to trust POs, it's not unique to school districts

Comment: I put on a downvote because the second paragraph isn't really accurate in my experience. The PO is used to officially indicate goods being received, which may involve immediate payment before processing. To the extent payment terms are set for after receipt of goods, that is used precisely because it ensures that the purchaser has the power, and the vendor has no opportunity to receive payment without fulfilling the order. Longer payment terms are used to gain the purchaser more 'time value of money' by deferring the payment into the future.

Comment: This distinction is relevant to the OP, because it highlights precisely the risk inferred by his/her question: Does the vendor bear any risk when receiving delayed payment, often through use of PO's from purchasers? Answer: Yes, if you don't receive payment until after, you face the risk that the purchaser may decline to pay you, or pay you later than agreed, with little recourse except to attempt legal action, possibly at some expense to yourself.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the headline question: it depends. The capital needed to carry over between delivery, invoicing, through to payment can very much depend on what your exact business is.

For example, you're a software company selling pre-written software. The incremental cost of selling another copy is near 0, you just churn out an e-mail with the license key. The additional capital needed due to the extra delay in accepting PO's are low. The opposite would be a low-gross margin business, like catering.

Another option is known as *factoring*. Here a finance company takes the invoice (at time of shipment) and pays you immediately at a discount. The factoring company then takes payment from the customer. This is a loan, and depends on the creditworthiness of both parties. A school district or governmental body is unlikely to disappear or go bankrupt, versus a PO from a small business. Factoring can be expensive from 1-4% per month.

Alternative means of payment, namely credit cards, are aware of these costs and charge more as a result. When a business takes a company credit card (purchasing card or P-card), their [interchange rates](https://usa.visa.com/content/dam/VCOM/download/merchants/visa-usa-interchange-reimbursement-fees.pdf) approach 3%, around twice as much as a consumer transaction.

Comment: Are there really factoring services that would step in for a small-time supplier like the OP considering starting a new business? The expense there would be far higher than 1-4% [which would be about the same as the cut taken by a credit card processor], if it is available at all. I'm not aware of this being offered except to large reputable businesses. The risk otherwise would be too great for the factoring company.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon 4% for a loan over a month is a 48% annual rate. They can take quite a bit of risk at that level.

Comment: 4% applied on a PO with 30 day payment terms, is about flat with the merchant fees associated with a credit card transaction, yet the factoring company has assumed (1) risk of non-performance by the vendor + (2) risk of non-payment by the customer.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon Factoring would apply to invoices, which are issued at or after delivery. The risk of non-performance, assuming no fraud, is not an issue, particularly if the vendor obtains a delivery or acceptance certificate. The risk would be limited to withholding of payment due to e.g. defects. The risk of insolvency of the customer can be separately assessed and is independent of the creditworthiness of the vendor. All companies, when accepting PO/terms vs credit card or up-front payment, should be doing this anyway

Answer (score 1):

The basic thrust of your question seems to be around whether suppliers need to be prepared for a delayed payment sales model 'if they accept POs'.

Technically a PO could require immediate payment terms, which would put the vendor in the position of power, that it could potentially purchase its own supplies when it receives payment, and then use those supplies to fulfill an order. It is quite common for a contract to indicate 'payment terms' that would involve payment being made some number of days after signing or after receipt of goods. In some cases, a deposit of some % may be required in advance when the PO is signed, with the remainder due on delivery or some number of days afterwards

What payment terms you will likely see, will depend on your location and industry. Vendors would like to be paid up front. Customers would like to pay 90 days after delivery or later. What is common in one place, will not always be common in another place or industry. You can rest assured however, that the most likely scenario is that whoever is the larger entity [you or the school district, in your case], is the one who will get what they want.

This means that new businesses, who have little negotiating power, will likely be forced to offer services with delayed payment. This creates 2 important considerations for such a business:

(1) The cost of having the capital in place, to afford buying supplies before production (if relevant to you). If your business relies on a relatively small profit margin, this cost can be significant (like if you opened a small bakery making cakes for a school district, perhaps your ingredients and staff costs would represent 80% of the sale price, meaning you would need to have $8,000 available capital if you were going to sell $10,000 / month, with annual profit of $24k.)

(2) The risk that your customer never pays you, and thus you need to pursue them legally for damages (which could be costly, stressful, and time consuming for you).

Comment: The entity with the bargaining power is only loosely correlated to size, it's more about economic moat.  If the transaction is for a commodity, then the purchaser can dictate their own terms, and shop for a supplier willing to abide by them.  But if it's highly specialized, then the purchaser is stuck with whatever terms the vendor agrees to.